# Git Pull Request: Merge from branch into another empty branch - No changes between selected branches

Tags: git

I am trying to write up some documentation to get my coworkers to start collaborating using Git. I have two very basic branches, master and development. Originally, they both had the same content but I deleted everything from master to make a pull request example. I am using Azure Repos if that matters.

When I try to make a pull request merging development into master, it tells me there are no changes between branches. Is this expected before for merging a branch with an empty one? How can I make this work? When I try the other way of master into development, the merge would be just deleting all files as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with git, you will have two local copies of each branch:

- `master` (your local copy of `master` where you apply changes via commits)
- `origin\master` (your local copy of the remote repository's `master` branch where you apply changes via push)
- `development` (your local copy of `development` where you apply changes via commits)
- `origin\development` (your local copy of the remote repository's `development` branch where you apply changes via push)

In this scenario, you would probably have a branch policy in place which prevents users from directly committing code to `master`. This would require anyone who wants to merge code into `master` to do so via a pull request.

When you deleted everything from the `master` branch, how did you do that?

Did you commit and push those changes into `origin\master`?

From what you are describing, it sounds like your local `master` branch has changed, but your remote repository `origin/master` does not know about those changes.

If you are on the `master` branch and run the following command:

`git log --oneline`

What does the command line output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i deleted/committed locally and then pushed those changes to remote. In the remote's dashboard (Azure), the repo was empty but after using the log command and then checking commit history in Azure, it looks like there was no actual commit but somehow the repo was empty. I just redid the steps and it worked as expected.. Strange